# "Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' > Failed to generate v1 signature" exception while compiling Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

i have a problem with the compilation of flutter

i have already try to debug without success

Resolving dependencies...                                           4,5s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > Failed to generate v1 signature
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        11,3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I think is a problem from gradle but i don't know how to solve that

Comment: Can you provide more informations about `flutter doctor`

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17763.503],
    locale fr-FR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: adb.
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.35.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Answer (score 3):

> X Android SDK file not found: adb. 
>    X Flutter plugin not installed.
>    X Dart plugin not installed.

You need to install Dart and Flutter :

 Android Studio:Go to Tools>SDK Manager>Plugins 

VS Code :
 [image]

Comment: Answer Updated !